# Как из базы данных получить id по диапазону?

Tags: php, mysql

Как из базы данных получить id по диапазону?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE id BETWEEN 5 AND 15
```

Comment: от 5 до 15 да???

Comment: Не за что, жмите галку под пальцем вниз рядом с моим ответом)